# using nested destructuring with aliasing for javascript Object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this object

```
const storeObj = {
    name: {
        firstName: 'abc'
    }
}
```

I can do alias by assigning `name` to `username`

```
const { name: username } = storeObj
```

I can do nested destructuring like so

```
const { name: { firstName } } = storeObj
```

Can I use them both together? I want to achieve one line when aliasing aka renanming and nested destructuring.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, just put those two together - when you want to assign to a different variable name than the property name, put the new variable name after a colon. This works regardless of the level of the nested object.

```js
const storeObj = {
    name: {
        firstName: 'abc'
    }
}
const { name: { firstName: username } } = storeObj;
console.log(username);
```